# PHP: search array(A) value in array(B) and get 2nd "column" value

Tags: php, arrays

I have `Array(A) = ('red','green')`

and

```
Array(B) 
( array('colour' => "red", 'name_cz' =>"cervena"),
array('colour' => "green", 'name_cz' =>"zelena"),
array('colour' => "blue", 'name_cz' =>"modra"),
array('colour' => "yellow", 'name_cz' =>"zluta")
)
```

I need to take every value of Array(A), compare it with Array(B) colour values and if it finds get its name_cz value...

so the output of the example should be like `$result = (array("cervena", "zelena");`

Thanks for help, subii

Comment: What have you tried so far, I hate to be that guy but honestly pal, this is not the most complicated thing in the world, show us where you got stuck and I'm more than happy to help, I aint writing code for you though.

Comment: Turns out other people will though

Comment: This can easily be refactored. You can use `array_filter` twice to achieve this in [one single line](https://3v4l.org/BAjJU). Loop the `data` and the `colours` and return those that match.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a million ways to do this.

Here's how I'd write this:

```
<?php


$a = array('red','green');

$b = array(
    array('colour' => "red", 'name_cz' =>"cervena"),
    array('colour' => "green", 'name_cz' =>"zelena"),
    array('colour' => "blue", 'name_cz' =>"modra"),
    array('colour' => "yellow", 'name_cz' =>"zluta")
);

$result = array_filter($b,function($v) use ($a){
    return in_array($v['colour'],$a);
});
$result = array_column($result,'name_cz');
print_r($result); // Array ( [0] => cervena [1] => zelena )
```

Comment: I know it's cool to help a fellow coder out but in cases like this I find it annoying that OP hasn't even told us what they tried, or where they got stuck, good on you tho pal, have a +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

This are two tasks, filter the lists for matching elements and map them.

```php
$data = [ 
  ['colour' => "red", 'name_cz' =>"cervena"],
  ['colour' => "green", 'name_cz' =>"zelena"],
  ['colour' => "blue", 'name_cz' =>"modra"],
  ['colour' => "yellow", 'name_cz' =>"zluta"]
];

$colours = ['red','green'];

// filter by colour
$filtered = array_filter(
  $data,
  function($translation) use ($colours) {
    // return true if the element matches
    return (in_array($translation['colour'], $colours));
  }
);

// map to string array
$mapped = array_map(
  fn ($translation) => $translation['name_cz'],
  $filtered
);

var_dump($mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *array_intersect_key* for this task:

```
$colors = [ 'red', 'green' ];

$array = [
    [ 'colour' => 'red', 'name_cz' => 'cervena' ],
    [ 'colour' => 'green', 'name_cz' => 'zelena' ],
    [ 'colour' => 'blue', 'name_cz' => 'modra' ],
    [ 'colour' => 'yellow', 'name_cz' => 'zluta' ]
];

$result = array_intersect_key($array, array_map(fn($color) => [ 'colour' => $color ], $colors));

print_r($result);
```